# Entity Framework - logical deletion on collections

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm curious on an elegant solution for POCOs with Entity Framework, with collections of logically deleted children.

This is trivial to implement in a repository or over a DbSet, but when it comes to controlling the population of various `ICollection` based properties of a class can we prevent logically deleted items being retrieved by Entity Framework?

For example, the majority of my entities have a DeleteStamp, which indicates whether an item is logically deleted. Is there a way to tell Entity Framework to populate its collections but to ignore items for example `WHERE DeleteStamp IS NULL`.

This could be accomplished in nHibernate for example when declaring a `<set />` element and specifying the `where` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so.  You have to build Respository rules and ADD dynamic lambda rules.
The basic query sets are easily managed as you note.
But over navigation props i have been coding extras. :-(
And generically that is very complex.

eg A repository with get that accepts a predicate Expression of Func. You then extend this. Expression tree management .

I cant find conditional naviation props in the new version specs either.

[ef6 specification](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=specs)